# Access specific list parts in Racket/Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, racket

I am having trouble figuring out how to access specific pair information in Racket.

Say I am given some list like this:

```
(define database-of-components
'((p1 200 (2 p2) (3 p3))
(p2 8 (2 p4))
(p3 60 (1 p5) (2 p6) (3 p7))
(p4 2)
(p5 2)
...
))
```

How am I able to access the data contained in some individual `pn`? Say I am trying to get just 200 from `p1` or just 60 from `p3`... how might I do this?

Note: This is obviously for a homework assignment but this question is just to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up [assq](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=assq#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._assq%29%29) and friends (`assoc`, `assv`):

```
> (assq 'p1 database-of-components)
'(p1 200 (2 p2) (3 p3))
> (second (assq 'p1 database-of-components))
200
> (second (assq 'p3 database-of-components))
60
```